# How to implement Realm database in android library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Install Realm as a Gradle plugin.

Step 1: Add the class path dependency to the project level build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.3.1"
    }
}
```

Step 2: Apply the realm-android plugin to the top of the application level build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Step 3 : add dependencies

```
 implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'
```

But when I build my project this error find :

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

Full build.gradle(Module) file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfirastapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'
}
```

and build.gradle(Project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.4"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please share your full gradle file

Comment: yes, I have update my full gradle file both project and Module on my Question

Comment: compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0' please change this last with  implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:2.0.0'

Comment: change but still same error

Answer (score 0):

> replace all 'compile' with 'implementation' in gradle file